# Updating a entry in every section of the xml file

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have this xml file where i want to add the "`<Department>Sales</Department>"` to every person tag. I want to add this using powershell and keep the format. any pointers will be helpful

Before
:

```
<employees>
    <person>
         <name>John</name>
         <Age>36</Age>
    </person>
    <person>
         <name>Jack</name>
         <Age>38</Age>
    </person>
    <person>
         <name>Jill</name>
         <Age>34</Age>
    </person>
</employees>
```

After:

```
<employees>
    <person>
         <name>John</name>
         <Age>36</Age>
         <Department>Sales</Department>
    </person>
    <person>
         <name>Jack</name>
         <Age>38</Age>
         <Department>Sales</Department>
    </person>
    <person>
         <name>Jill</name>
         <Age>34</Age>
         <Department>Sales</Department>
    </person>
</employees>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example xml is missing a root tag, so if I add that:

```
[xml]$xml = @'
<root>
<employees>
    <person>
         <name>John</name>
         <Age>36</Age>
    </person>
    <person>
         <name>Jack</name>
         <Age>38</Age>
    </person>
    <person>
         <name>Jill</name>
         <Age>34</Age>
    </person>
</employees>
</root>
'@
```

You can loop through the employees->person nodes and append a new node to each of them:

```
$xml.DocumentElement.employees.person | ForEach-Object {
    $newTag = $xml.CreateElement('Department')
    $newTag.InnerText = 'Sales'
    $_.AppendChild($newTag)
}
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <employees>
    <person>
      <name>John</name>
      <Age>36</Age>
      <Department>Sales</Department>
    </person>
    <person>
      <name>Jack</name>
      <Age>38</Age>
      <Department>Sales</Department>
    </person>
    <person>
      <name>Jill</name>
      <Age>34</Age>
      <Department>Sales</Department>
    </person>
  </employees>
</root>
```